# treatment of alkyl chloride with aqueous KOH and alcoholic KOH

Tags: organic-chemistry

The treatment of alkyl chloride with aqueous KOH leads to the formation of alcohol but in the presence of alcoholic KOH alkenes are major product. Why?

Answer (score 0):

[image]
I have added an image to answer your question, always look at the acid base reactions which are possible to take place, that helps in understanding the reactions and their respective mechanisms.

Comment: Please cite your source, and consider typing what's included in the image.

Comment: As I couldn't type the reactions as answer I wrote them on MS-word and uploaded the screenshot.